# iframe parent.function() call is undefined when used in Phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, iframe, cordova

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for help. Here is my situation:

I have Phonegap 0.9.5 setup and I am making an application in Eclipse. I have everything setup fine and in my app  assets/www/index.html of my Phonegap application:

```
<iframe id='downloader' frameborder='0' style='width:100%' src='http://www.myste.com/mobile/index.html'></iframe>
```

http://www.myste.com/mobile/index.html has this button:

```
 <input style="position:relative;top:200px;z-index:5;" type="button" onclick="alert(parent.location.href)" value="DOES MOM EXIST?" />';
```

But for some reason, I am returned an "undefined". My ultimate goal is to have the button in the iframe call a function in the parent (assets/www/index.html):

```
onclick="parent.somefunction();"
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like `window.top.location.href`?

Comment: Is this iframe's parent on a different domain or subdomain?

Comment: The parent is the assets/www/index.html of Phonegap

Comment: And where is the iframe loading from?

Comment: assets/www/index.html of Phonegap.

Comment: Weird, not sure. I'd try this outside of phonegap first to rule out variables and then if it works drop it in to phonegap.

Comment: @Mauvis: Well I tried doing this:

`assets/www/index.html (Phonegap's main file)`

`iframe [points to offsite index.html] (the original iframe now with no button asking for the parent)`

`iframe_2 [points to offsite but.html] (an iframe inside the original iframe with a button that has  <input style="position:relative;top:200px;z-index:5;" type="button" onclick="alert(parent.location.href)" value="DOES MOM EXIST?" />';)`

But for an odd reason I still get undefined....Why is this? It should return index.html, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing... to sum it up, I did you suggestion and still undefined.